# Is there a way to create an exception in django 1.0 csrf protection?

Tags: django, csrf, amcharts

I know there is in the [development version](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/?from=olddocs) of Django, but I don't see this in [Django 1.0](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/csrf/). I took a look of the code and such an exception is definitely not built in. I need to have this ability as I can't add the csrf middleware token to a third party flash app I am using which needs to make a POST request back to django. :(

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Err... upgrade to Django 1.1? It's pretty stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is simply recreate the token using the middleware and add it into the view and then making it accessible in the template for JavaScript/Flash.